# How to write SELECT FROM testing WHERE int_col + int_col2 > 123 in mongodb query?

Tags: mongodb, pymongo

I am trying to change a part of database from MySQL to MongoDB,
but I had a problem with `SELECT  FROM testing WHERE int_col + int_col2 > 123`. I am trying to change it to MongoDB query but I can't.

Please help me, thanks!.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Easiest way is to split it into 2 actions in an aggregation pipeline:

```
db.getCollection(collection).aggregate(
    [
        { 
            "$addFields" : {
                "sum" : {
                    "$sum" : [
                        "$int_col", 
                        "$int_col2"
                    ]
                }
            }
        }, 
        { 
            "$match" : {
                "sum" : {
                    "$gt" : 123
                }
            }
        }
    ])
```